# D3 fisheye distortion issue for simple line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, fisheye

I am bit new to d3.js, looking to implement fish-eye/magnifier to the simple line chart, the problem am facing i do not see any change/movement in the chart when mouse is moved, what could be the problem with my code, could anyone please point me out in right direction, any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the links am referring [`link`](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye) to, my plunker [`link`](https://plnkr.co/edit/qJnZ0yc1celwv2ynIySZ?p=preview)